# Reading Large MDB file in Android

Tags: android

I have one application which is developed in VB and it has database in MDB. Size of the MDB is large. Now I want to read that MDB by the android application. I want to read that MDB in my android application. The size of the MDB is large I want on selective data only not complete database. My main concern is how to read MDB file by the Android programing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Java library to do this, which you can include in your application?  That's probably where I'd start, if you must read this file *on* the device, and can't either convert it or access it over the internet via some intermediary application.